# How to enter string in browser address bar by using getText() method, in selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I wants to open a new tab which contains a dynamic url. The url I am getting store in `str` variable as shown below:

```
String str = WebPublish_URL.getText();
```

Now I wants a tab with url by using `getText()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways to do this. In below examples I am doing following steps,

- Launching `https://google.com`
- Searching for `facebook` text and getting the `facebook` `URL`
- Opening `facebook` within and different tab.

**Solution#1**: Get the `URL` value and load it in existing browser.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");
driver.get(facebookUrl);
```

**Solution#2**: Using `window handles`.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");
        
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open()");
        
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        
driver.get(facebookUrl);
```

**Solution#3**: By creating new `driver` instance. It's not recommended but it is also a possible way to do this.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");

/*Create an another instance of driver.*/   
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(facebookUrl);
```

**Update with Selenium 4**:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
driver.navigate().to(facebookUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getText` is to `get the text` from a **web element**. If your `str` contains a `URL` and you want to **open a new tab** and then load `str containing URL`, try the below steps :

to open a new tab

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
```

once it's opened up you would need to switch as well.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

so basically, in sequence :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.get(str);
```

Comment: It is working for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good ! Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.